# [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect: [IM004][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, freetds, unixodbc

I have defined the connection steps below but I get an error. Tried most of the available drivers in /usr/lib64/ but still same error.

> /usr/local/etc/freetds.conf

```
#Server defined by Victor
[THESERVER]
   host = 172.xx.xxx.xx
   port = 1433
   tds version = 7.2
```

> /etc/odbc.ini

```
# Defined by victor
[CRMCONNECT]
Description = "CRMConnect"
Driver = msSQL
Trace = Yes
Servername = THESERVER
hostname = 172.xx.xxx.xx
Database = "THE_DB"
UserName = "user"
Password = "password"
PROTOCOL = TCPIP
```

> /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[msSQL]
Description = msSQL Driver
Driver = /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.2.0.0
fileusage=1
dontdlclose=1


command
[root@darubini ~]# isql -v "CRMCONNECT" "user" "password"
```

> ```
> Error message
> [IM004][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed
> [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
> ```

Below is a snapshot of the available libodbc and libtds drivers . Where would i be going wrong.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `libtds.so`. What flavor of Linux are you running? Under CentOS, for example, my `odbcinst.ini` driver line is `Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so`.

Comment: This is the line that i am using/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.2.0.0  mine does not have /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so . REDHAT-4 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 1 01:33:01 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Ooof, RedHat 4? That went out of production support in 2012. What version of FreeTDS are you running? The command `tsql -C` should give more information.